# html table email creative

Tags: html, html-email

I have this email creative:

http://lirantadmor.co.il/email

I want the new balance ad at the end to come a bit up and be right after the blue and green boxes.

how can I manage it in an easy way without the need to change the all setup of the tables ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest getting a tool called firebug for firefox and chrome. It will allow you to work this sort of stuff out. I took a look at your link and my first impression is that you need to change the way your table is structured.

Basically what is happening is that the bar on the left is higher than the 3 columns on the right. The table holding the bar on the left and these columns is thus the size of the table holding both.

You will need to split this up into 2 tables to bring the bottom box upwards.

Another option could be to use negative margin on the box at the bottom. But i must stress that this may not work in all email clients. So you will need to test test test!